# Is it possible to call a public array from another contract?

Tags: solidity, arrays, interfaces

Let's say there is a `uint[] public MyArray` declared in `contract_A`.

Is there a possiblility to create an `interface contract_A` that would allow to read the values in  `MyArray` from another contract, or is it absolutely necessary to build a getter for `MyArray` in `contract_A`?

Asking this because of the code size limit, if there are a lot of arrays in contract_A, would be convenient to not build a getter for all of them (they need to be read by another contract).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All public variables automatically generate a getter function so you don't need to explicitly create new ones.

Here is an example:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

contract A {
     uint[1] public MyArray;
     constructor() public {
         MyArray[0] = 56;
     }
  
}
contract B {
    function DoIt() public returns (uint) {
        A contr = new A();
        return contr.MyArray(0);
    }
}
```

You should deploy contract `B` and call its `DoIt` function to get result `56`.

Comment: Thank you. When doing `new A()`, does it create a new instance of `contract A`? Is there a way to point to an already existing `contract A`?

Comment: Yes, it creates a new instance. You can point to an existing `A` with `A contr = A(addressOfA);`

Comment: How can you access to array's "length" property?  Following your approach I'm getting: "Member "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup"

Comment: You can't. Only a getter for the data is autogenerated. You have to create a function for that explicitly.